# php INSERT mysql 5.7

Tags: php, mysql

I use to insert values in php like this:

```
$sql = " INSERT INTO `table` (name, email) VALUES ('$name','$email') ";
```

considering that my table has the following columns: id, name, email, address, phone

in mysql 5.7 it won't let my do that query above anymore, cause it's says address don't have a default value.

I add a default value for it on mysql, but some fields dont allow default value, like blob, text...

my question is: Do I always have to describe every column of my table in my query so it can work? Like:

```
$sql = " INSERT INTO `table` (id,name, email, address, phone) 
VALUES ('', '$name','$email', '', '') ";
```

Comment: ***[Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. [Escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!  Learn [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Why concatenate the string instead of using [prepared statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) ?

Comment: If you could have a default value for BLOB columns, what would it be?

Comment: You don't have to describe every column for every query you make, but particular for `INSERT` queries, you have to make sure that the columns you *don't* specify either have a default value, or can be `NULL`.

Comment: You don't need to insert id because if its set to auto increment / primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to describe every column for every query you make, but particularly for `INSERT` queries, you have to make sure that the columns you *don't* specify either have a default value, or can be `NULL`.

For other queries, such as `SELECT` or `UPDATE`, you can choose just the ones you want without regard what the content is (of course same applies for `UPDATE` as `INSERT`, that columns which cannot be NULL, can't have a NULL-value in it).

You can alter your table such that the values you don't always insert either have a default value, or just set them to NULL by default (if you don't supply a value for that column upon inserting).

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
CHANGE column_name column_name type DEFAULT NULL
```